# Kubernetes - Pass the cronjob schedule to container env

Tags: kubernetes

Let's say I have such CronJob definition:

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"  # pass this value to container's env
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: cronjob-test
            image: myiamge:latest
            imagePullPolicy: Never
            env:
            - name: schedule
              value: # pass the schedule value here 
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

How do I pass the `schedule` value from the `CronJob.spec` into `CronJob.spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec.containers.env`? Is it even possible?

Normally, I would do something like this:

```
valueFrom:
  fieldRef:
    fieldPath: spec.timezone
```

But in this case, it won't get this value.

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately,  `schedule` should be certain value when `CronJob` defines. And the values referred by `fieldRef` is passed to its container as the env variables when your pod(container) run, so `fieldRef` cannot pass the certain value to `schedule` when the CronJob defines. Usually, in this use case, a template format is appropriate. For instance like Helm and similar ones.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
:
spec:
  schedule: {{ .Values.schedule }}
```

You can replace `schedule` value using Helm format.

```
// Values.yaml in the Helm format
schedule: '"*/1 * * * *"'
```